# Invocation of a trusted NodeJS script tries to connect to unkown IP

Tags: malware, node.js

I have a houskeeping script which I invoked using `node index.js` which got me this output

[image]

The error is because you cannot connect to the IP, but why would it try to connect to it in the first place?

A reverse DNS lookup says that the domain associated with the IP is `199.ry.cz` which has a parked domain page and isn't on any blacklists.

When I ran my script again via `node index.js` it ran normally.

My script uses these npm libraries: `lodash, node-fetch, fs, tinyqueue, url, tall, cheerio`

It does scrape over bookmarked links, so there's a chance this IP is related to that, but the way such errors are handled for my bookmarked links is different than the output here.

Does this look like suspicious activity? I'm on `ubuntu 16.04` with `node v8.12.0` installed from [Nodesource PPA](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md#installation-instructions)

Comment: could it be from a temp redirect of something you intended to connect to?

Comment: That is possible, and that'd explain it too. I guess I'm less concerned now since people didn't _recognize_ this as something malicious yet.